# How do I create a Deny From All Except List SES Authorization Policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authorization, amazon-ses

I'm using AWS SES to send emails from several different platforms. I need to lock down our domain's verified identity to only allow sends from a list of specific from addresses.

I hit two main problems when trying to make this work:

1. If I combine a Deny policy with an Allow policy then only the first address in the **FromAddress** condition is permitted to send. All others return an error.
2. If I do not include a Deny policy then all addresses are allowed to send, even addresses not in the list of permitted email addresses.

Below is an example of a combined Deny + Allow policy that I tried. I went through AWS documentation a ton to determine what's permitted. From what I can tell the **FromAddress** condition supports arrays (AWS lists), and using **ForAnyValue:StringEquals** should work like an OR operator. I'm probably missing something simple.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "stid",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": [
            "ses:SendEmail",
            "ses:SendRawEmail",
            "ses:SendTemplatedEmail",
            "ses:SendBulkTemplatedEmail"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:this-is-too-secret",
        "Condition": {}
    },
    {
        "Sid": "stid2",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": [
            "ses:SendEmail",
            "ses:SendRawEmail",
            "ses:SendTemplatedEmail",
            "ses:SendBulkTemplatedEmail"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:this-is-too-secret",
        "Condition": {
            "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                "ses:FromAddress": [
                    "example1@domain.com",
                    "example2@domain.com",
                    "example3@domain.com",
                    "example4@domain.com",
                    "example5@domain.com"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking back, I should have seen this sooner. You can accomplish this using **Deny**, **ForAllValues**, and **StringNotEquals**. Essentially, if the provided **FromAddress** equals any in the list it will fail the **StringNotEquals** condition, which will invert the Deny, and allow the email to go through.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
  "Sid": "stid",
  "Effect": "Deny",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "*"
  },
  "Action": [
    "ses:SendEmail",
    "ses:SendRawEmail",
    "ses:SendTemplatedEmail",
    "ses:SendBulkTemplatedEmail"
  ],
  "Resource": "arn:this-is-too-secret",
  "Condition": {
    "ForAllValues:StringNotEqualsIgnoreCase": {
      "ses:FromAddress": [
            "example1@domain.com",
            "example2@domain.com",
            "example3@domain.com",
            "example4@domain.com",
            "example5@domain.com"
        ]
    }
  }
}
]
}
```